# On uninstalling application getting 'Unfortunately package installer has stopped working"

Tags: android

Read before marking it as duplicate,I started getting error: system UI has stopped on motoZ2. I tried to figure out what is going wrong but ended up with nothing then I decided to uninstall all the installed app on which I came to know one app is giving this package installer error, I then decided to clear that app's data or try uninstalling this app from settings->app it didnt work even when I scrolled down to that app system UI crashed again. I searched alot but haven't found any solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Package installer is application which was being crashed in your devices for some reason.You might need to update your devices firmware to latest version.Its Package installer app which was not able to run for some reason.

Comment: just updated my device to latest updates. seems like everything is updated and yes I already know that my package installer is crashing but couldn't find out yet to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error.

To resolve this issue, first, you have to check the size of your app icon or other icons and images used in your application. If anyone of them an icon or image size is too large in that case.

Or

You can try in android studio 'File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart'

Or

You can try to uninstall the application, Restart your mobile device and then try to re-installer the application